# Spring action for download not working in Android browsers

Tags: java, android, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm developing a web application using JSP and Spring MVC.

In my controller I have an action to download APK files:

```
@Controller("ApplicationController")
public class ApplicationController {
....

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getApp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getApp(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\test.apk");
        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(fis);
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.apk");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
        response.flushBuffer();
    }
 ....
}
```

In a page I have a link to call this action:

```
<a href="/getApp" target="_blank">Get App</a>
```

This link works in PC browsers, but when used in Android browsers like Chrome, download fails.

**ADDED:**

Before, I use that link through a SSL connection, but I've tested that via a simple http connection and it worked. I think this is a problem with my SSL connection and Android download manager!!!!

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: What are the symptoms of `in Android browsers like Chrome, download fails`? Please copy&paste error messages, if any.

Comment: @greybeard There's no debug error, just when touch download link in Android Chrome browser, the browser asks for downloading the file, but after confirming download, Android show a toast notification containing 'Download was unsuccessful!' message

Comment: Does your controller works when you download another type of file instead an apk?

Comment: @eltabo I've tried that with a text file and the same problem occurred.

Comment: @eltabo I connect to the web application through a SSL connection. Can browser reject download request because of my SSL certificate?

Comment: @eltabo I've changed my connection from a SSL connection to a simple HTTP connection and it works well. How can I use SSL connection without any problem?

Answer (score 0):

After days, as conclusion, I think when we click a download link in an android web browser, this link will be opened by Android Download Manager-a third party application- so this application can't make a safe and reliable connection to my server through a SSL connection because of not-verified certificate.

However, I've solved my problem by switching download HTTPS request to an HTTP request to download the file.